# C++ subclassing

Tags: c++, constructor, subclass

I have problems figuring out why I cannot compile my program. I have a `Storage` template class which looks like

```
template <class _T>
class Storage {
    ...
    Storage<_T> &provider;
public:
    Storage(int n)
    : provider(self) {
        ...
    };

    Storage(const Storage<_T> &orig, int offset = 0, int size = 0)
    : provider(orig.provider) {
        ...
    }
};
```

From this base class I wish to derive a `LinearSpace` class:

```
struct Structure {
    /** How many points in the space */
    idx_t records;
    /** Number of different kinds of vectors (position, velocity, etc...) */
    idx_t vectors;
    /** Dimensionality of one vector */
    idx_t dimensionality;
};

template <class _T>
class LinearSpace : public Storage<_T> {
    ...
    Structure structure;
public:
    LinearSpace(int recs, int vecs, int dim)
    : Storage<_T>(recs*vecs*dim), structure({recs, vecs, dim}) {
        ...
    };

    LinearSpace(const LinearSpace<_T> &orig, int index = 0)
    : Storage<_T>(orig, index) {
        ...
    }
};
```

Everything is fine up to this point. I can easily construct both `Storage` and `LinearSpace` objects using all constructors I've defined. However, when I try to subclass `LinearSpace` as follows

```
template <class _T>
class Record : public LinearSpace<_T> {
    ...
public:
    Record(int vecs, int dim)
    : LinearSpace<_T>(1, vecs, dim) {
        ...
    };

    Record(const LinearSpace<_T> &orig, int index = 0)
    : LinearSpace<_T>(orig, index) {
        ...
    }
};
```

and try to construct a `Record` from a `LinearSpace` and an index (second constructor of `Record`, which calls the second constructor of `LinearSpace`) I get an error from the compiler, which complains that `no matching constructor for initialisation of LinearSpace<type>` exists. The error rises when I try the following:

```
LinearSpace<TYPE> space(2, 2, 2);
Record<TYPE> record(space, 0);
```

I don't get it... The constructor of `Record` regularly calls the constructor of `LinearSpace` and gives a reference to a `LinearSpace` object and an integer. Such constructor clearly exists, since I can write

```
LinearSpace<TYPE> space2(space, 0);
```

without any problem. So, I don't know why I cannot compile my program!

Sorry for the long post... Anyone has an idea of what I'm getting wrong?

Thanks in advance!

P.S. I don't know if that matters but I'm running on OS X 10.9 with the latest version of Xcode (which uses LLVM 5.1)

Comment: can you post your *specific* error? Have you tried removing the `const`ness in the ctor to verify it's nothing to do with passing in non-const objects?

Comment: Note that formally the code is invalid since `_T` is a name reserved to the implementation. All names starting with underscore followed by uppercase are reserved. And so are names containing two consecutive underscores. In addition, as I recall, any name starting with underscore is reserved in the global namespace.

Comment: Please post a short, **complete** program that demonstrates your error. Delete all of the lines that do not contribute to the error, and copy-paste whatever is left. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve or http://SSCCE.org for more info.

Comment: @MrDuk The _specific_ error is `No matching constrictor for initialization of LinearSpace<double>`. I also tried omitting the `const` but nothing changes.
@Cheersandhth.-Alf Thank you for the info, I will try to avoid it in the future. Actually I have included all the code above in some `COMPASS` namespace!
@Robᵩ I already did! The complete classes are much wider, I just included the parts which seem to cause issues: definitions with the constructors I use and the two lines which rise the error in the main program. I'm still testing the classes so there are no other lines inside `main` at all!

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

For some reason (as @MrDuk suggested) the `const` specifier (in the `Record` constructor) was causing the problem. Removing it would not make any difference with Apple's LLVM 5.1 but it solved the issue when using GNU GCC 4.9, which I just tested.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score -1):

The following code compiles with Visual C++ 12.0 and 4.8.2.

It is identical to your code except that Smalltalk (?) `self` has been replaced with C++ `*this`.

```
template <class _T>
class Storage {
    //...
    Storage<_T> &provider;
public:
    Storage(int n)
    : provider(*this) {     //! "self" -> "*this"
        //...
    };

    Storage(const Storage<_T> &orig, int offset = 0, int size = 0)
    : provider(orig.provider) {
        //...
    }
};

using idx_t = int;

struct Structure {
    /** How many points in the space */
    idx_t records;
    /** Number of different kinds of vectors (position, velocity, etc...) */
    idx_t vectors;
    /** Dimensionality of one vector */
    idx_t dimensionality;
};

template <class _T>
class LinearSpace : public Storage<_T> {
    //...
    Structure structure;
public:
    LinearSpace(int recs, int vecs, int dim)
    : Storage<_T>(recs*vecs*dim), structure({recs, vecs, dim}) {
        //...
    };

    LinearSpace(const LinearSpace<_T> &orig, int index = 0)
    : Storage<_T>(orig, index) {
        //...
    }
};

template <class _T>
class Record : public LinearSpace<_T> {
    //...
public:
    Record(int vecs, int dim)
    : LinearSpace<_T>(1, vecs, dim) {
        //...
    };

    Record(const LinearSpace<_T> &orig, int index = 0)
    : LinearSpace<_T>(orig, index) {
        //...
    }
};

int main()
{
    using TYPE = double;
    LinearSpace<TYPE> space(2, 2, 2);
    Record<TYPE> record(space, 0);
}
```

Given that the code compiles with two modern compilers, it looks like there is a problem with your compiler.

---

Please do read the C++ FAQ item titled **[“How do I post a question about code that doesn't work correctly?”](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/posting-code.html)**, especially points 5, 6 and 7.

Comment: Thank you for that, I actually have a `#define self *this` since I liked the keyword while using Objective-C. I also have typedefs for `idx_t = int` and `TYPE = double`, so my code is identical to yours. I'd say then that either my compiler has some issues or I'm messing this up in some other way... I will now try with GCC and let you know, thanks!